# How to set "Language Selector dropdown" required in node form

Tags: 7, forms, i18n-l10n

I want to know How to set "Language Selector Drop-Down " required in node form?

I tried to do this via hook_form_alter, but it seems $form['language'] is not created in this hook !

Is there any hook that let me modify language Drop-Down selector?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/144756/6568)

```
You can enable i18n_node module that is included in i18n module. Then:

    Go to edit the content type (admin/structure/types/manage/page).
    Open the 'Multilingual settings' tab.
    Check the 'Require language' checkbox.

Done.
```

**Multilingual content** must be installed at first and then in content type, **Multilingual settings** tab will be added